# After I configure my php.ini file to load the MySQL module, it doesn't appear in phpinfo() and I can't call to MySQL functions

Tags: php, mysql, apache2

sorry if this is a really silly question. I googled a lot and nothing came up

I have this in my php.ini file:

```
extension_dir="C:\Program Files\PHP\ext"
enable_dl = on
extension=php_mysql.dll
```

when I call the phpinfo() function it says that there aren't any loaded modules.

I am using the latest version of apache, php and MySQL in a windows operating systems.

Also, I have used a WAMP server but I prefer having things separately and I want to learn how to do it

Thanks in advance

Comment: try running php from the command line and post the output here

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the mysql extension itself in php.ini too. For example if you want to use mysqli, you need to add this to your php.ini file:

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

also make sure that you have this dll  file in your ext directory.

Comment: hi thank you for the answer.
I want to use php_mysql.dll and I have it on my php.ini file and it isn't working

Comment: Same, add the extension line 
    extension=php_mysql.dll
and make sure that this dll file in your ext directory, try restarting apache after doing this.

Comment: I added the extension line. A question: when does php.ini loads? do you I have to restart php? I already restarted apache and it isn't working